# Validating models using RegularExpression annotation

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I added a filter to my web api project to validate all models that are passed from the client. To validate the models, I'm using data annotations. It all seems to work fine except when I use a RegularExpression annotation.

This is the filter I have in my api:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
```

And this is the model property that's not validating correctly:

```
    [Required]
    [MinLength(8)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least one capital letter and one number")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

No matter what values i pass in the string, I keep getting an error. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$
```

Prob your expression returns `null` when password is well-formed.